# How do I indent every line?

Tags: equations, align

What I'm trying to achieve is to align all the equals signs above each other like this:

```
E[ag(X)+bh(X)] = aE[g(X)]+bE[h(x)]
               = io;garo;gira
               = AW$aryyy
               = .....
```

I've searched for 5 minutes and decided after not finding the answer that it would be easier to ask, I appreciate the help =)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Use the `align` or `alignat` environments

Answer (score 5):

> I've searched for five minutes ...

Where, may I ask? In a book or user guide on how to write math material using LaTeX, by any chance?

Anyway, I suggest you familiarize yourself with the [amsmath](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package and its many environments dedicated to typesetting math material. The `align*` environment may be what you need.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "align*" environment
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E} % expectations operator
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\E[ag(X)+bh(X)] &= a\E[g(X)]+b\E[h(x)]\\
                &= \text{io;garo;gira}\\ %% seriously?
                &= \text{AW\$aryyy}\\    %% you don't say!
                &= \dots
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```